# Por qué Random.Next() devuelve siempre el mismo número

Tags: c#, random

¿Por qué, si ejecuto mi metodo `LanzarDados()` multitud de veces dentro de un `For`, el `Random` me devuelve siempre el mismo número?

```
int[] tiradas = new int[3];

private int LanzarDados()
{
    return new Random().Next(1, 6);
}

public string Jugar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tiradas.Length; i++)
    {
        tiradas[i] = LanzarDados();
    }

    return ComprobarResultados() == true
        ? $"Partida ganada!!!, las tiradas fueron {tiradas[0]}, {tiradas[1]}, {tiradas[2]}"
        : $"Partida perdida..., las tiradas fueron {tiradas[0]}, {tiradas[1]}, {tiradas[2]}";
}

private bool ComprobarResultados()
{
    return Array.TrueForAll(tiradas, (x) => x == tiradas[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que quieres obtener un número aleatorio creas una nueva instancia de la clase `Random` (`new Random().Next(1,6)`)

La clase `Random` genera una secuencia de números pseudoaleatorios que dependen del valor de inicialización pasado al constructor. Es decir, sin inicializas el objeto `Random` con el mismo valor de inicialización obtienes la misma secuencia de números. En tu caso estás obteniendo siempre el primer número de la secuencia ya que cada vez creas una nueva instancia y, como no estás indicando ningún valor de inicialización, .NET genera un valor a partir del reloj del sistema.

Según la documentación de la propia clase `Random`:

> El valor de inicialización predeterminado se deriva del reloj del sistema y tiene una resolución finita. Como resultado, diferentes Random objetos que se crean en estrecha sucesión mediante una llamada al constructor predeterminado tendrán valores de inicialización predeterminados idénticos y, por consiguiente, generarán conjuntos idénticos de números aleatorios.

Para evitarlo tienes dos opciones:

1 Usar una única instancia de `Random` para generar los números:

```
int[] tiradas = new int[3];
Random rnd = new Random();
private int LanzarDados()
{
    return rnd.Next(1, 6);
}

public string Jugar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tiradas.Length; i++)
    {
        tiradas[i] = LanzarDados();
    }
    return ComprobarResultados() == true ? $"Partida ganada!!!, las tiradas fueron {tiradas[0]}, {tiradas[1]}, {tiradas[2]}" : $"Partida perdida..., las tiradas fueron {tiradas[0]}, {tiradas[1]}, {tiradas[2]}";
}

private bool ComprobarResultados()
{
    return Array.TrueForAll(tiradas, (x) => x == tiradas[0]);
}
```

2 Crear las instancias de la clase `Random` utilizando un valor de inicialización diferente cada vez.

Una solución que se suele utilizar en este segundo caso es el de utilizar como valor de inicialización un valor basado en la hora actual:

```
return new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF).Next(1, 6);
```

que sería un valor que cambiaría cada 100 nanosegundos. Sin embargo en tu caso, dado que las llamadas son tan seguidas es muy posible que se repitiesen valores de inicialización con lo que seguirías con el mismo problema.

Tendrías que implementar un sistema para generar números de inicialización diferentes en cada iteración con lo que añadirías bastante complejidad a tu código.

Comment: Sugerencia: ni mencionaría la segunda opción, porque ¿como puedes asegurarte de asignarle un diferente valor de inicialización a cada vez?  De hecho, es muy probable que `DateTime.Now.Ticks` devuelva el mismo valor a cada iteración, lo que produciría el mismo problema.

Comment: Cierto en este caso concreto que los números se generan en un bucle que además no tiene ninguna carga de proceso es muy probable que se dé el caso que comentas, aunque en otros escenarios puede ser una opción a tener en cuenta. Modifico la respuesta.

Comment: La semilla solo se debe iniciarlizar una vez, aparte si no es un sistema critico suele servir la propiedad millisecond de datetime.now para iniciar la semilla